# Ajax reload.delete other script

Tags: php, ajax, material-design-lite

I use ajax reload for my table.php page. I`m using material.min.js from google material design for some features like tooltips. But after the page reload with ajax, material.min.js stop working.

My index.php include table.php, where I have:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: "table.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(body){
          $(".page-content").html(body);
        }
      });
    },10000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: well, was the link to the material.min.js within your ".page-content" element? If so, does the content of `body` contain a replacement link?

Comment: the link to material.min.js in my index.php, but if I add the link to the reloaded page, the script still won`t work

Comment: what error do you get when you try to use it?

Comment: I don`t have any errors. But before reload I can use all of the material.min.js features, for example tooltips are displayed on hover. But after ajax reload, the tooltips stopped working.

Comment: probably you need to re-apply the tooltips to the new content, or use delegated events to detect the hover. Any event handlers you added at page load onto content within ".page-content" are destroyed when you replace that content with new HTML.

Comment: I can`t re-apply them, because all the features working on ready code, and I can`t rewrite all the material.min.js code

Comment: Can you show how you initialise an element to have a tooltip on it?

Comment: I don't know material.js but I should think it must be possible to tell the library to re-initialise or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all, I have find the answer with adding this:

> componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();